# Python: str.startswith() and string comparison "==" not working

Tags: python, string, comparison, python-2.x, python-2.6

I'm trying to read a string from a file and find words that start with `"'param."` This is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

inputfile = open('abc.json', 'r')

fieldnametemp = []

for line in inputfile:
    for word in line.split():
        if(word == "'fieldname':"):
            fieldnametemp.append(line.split(':')[1])

for element in fieldnametemp:
    print element
    if(element.startswith("'param.")):
        print 1
    else:
        print 0
```

And this is my output:

```
     'param.design_key',

    0
     'param.abc',

    0
     'param.def',

    0
```

Even if its start with "'param." it prints 0.

I also tried to use

```
if(element.split('.')[0] == "'param."):
```

instead of

```
if(element.startswith("'param.")):
```

but output is same. What's wrong and what can I do?

Comment: What do you get for `print repr(element)`? I suspect that the string isn't quite what you think it is (whitespace, unicode chars etc maybe?)

Comment: Use "param." instead of "'param.". You have single qoute (') at start of string 'param.

Comment: @advay.umare the single quote is also in the string being searched

Comment: Might be an indentation error in your question, but it looks like element actually starts with a whitespace

Comment: Is there some reason you aren't deserializing the JSON and manipulating the Python object to get what you want?

Comment: Can you provide the `abc.json`?

Comment: Try `if "'param." in element:` instead as a test.

Comment: @match I get " 'param.design_key',\n"

Comment: Yes, looks like there is a space there.

Comment: @quamrana It works! Thank u

Comment: Yes it is whitespace problem, thank u all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on this

```
for word in line.split():
        if(word == "'fieldname':"):
            fieldnametemp.append(line.split(':')[1])
```

every element in `fieldnametemp` starts with a whitespace. So the content of `element` when you do `element.startswith("'param.")` also starts with a whitespace, so you are actually doing:

```
 " 'param.abc'".startswith("'.param")
```

which is obviously false. you need to include the whitespace:

```
element.startswith(" 'param.")
```

Comment: I know that we have determined that there is some whitespace in there, but I don't see how your first chunk of code shows that this must be so.

Comment: `line.split()` splits at whitespaces and it yields `'fieldname':` ,, so there must be a whitespace behind the ':'. Next the line is split in a different way, at the ':'. Since we know that it is followed by a whitespace, the whitespace will be at the start of the  second entry of the `split()` result.

Comment: Ahh! Excellent deduction.